# How to create sas_token for azure table storage in jQuery app

Tags: javascript, azure, access-token

I'm building a jQuery web app that needs read-only access to an Azure Table Storage (and only one record at a time is requested - I pass in the PartitionKey and RowKey to get the result). I have included the nice Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library to help simplify my code (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-azure-storage-javascript-client-library-for-browsers-preview/).

I'm getting hung up generating a SAS_TOKEN to authenticate my access to the Azure Table. I've tried to find JS examples of exactly how to do this, but have been unsuccessful. The only request parameter that is important to me is the expiry time (2 minutes).

It seems like the Azure Storage JS library has a NodeJS function that will do this, but I don't know how to access that using jQuery code. And I can't find a pure JS example of how to take the various pieces of the puzzle to create the SAS token.

Here is a link to the nice Azure JS document related to table storage I've been using: https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like the Azure Storage JS library has a NodeJS function that
>   will do this, but I don't know how to access that using jQuery code.
>   And I can't find a pure JS example of how to take the various pieces
>   of the puzzle to create the SAS token.

General recommendation is **NOT** to create a SAS token on the client side. In order to create a SAS token, you would need account key and by doing it on the client side, you're exposing your account key to your users (they could very well view the source code and get the account key). Anyone who has an account key essentially becomes an administrator for that storage account.

Recommended approach would be to have a server-side endpoint in your application responsible for generating the SAS token. From the client side, you could make an AJAX request (using $.ajax) to this endpoint and get a SAS token.  Or you could generate SAS token on the server side and pass it as a parameter to the client side. This way you will be protecting your account key.

Comment: Yes, Gaurav - I now understand the security issue, and agree with your approach. Now I'm off to figure out the best way to implement this in my project. Thanks!